# Do Examples of "Scroll Loading" with FlatList Exist?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

The ReactNative documentation mentions that `FlatList` has the feature of "Scroll loading" on this page: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html

Does anyone know of examples of this feature?

Comment: You should change your question name. This question is not an example, but asking about examples in react documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
onEndReached = { this.handLoadMore }
onEndReachedThreshold = { 100 }
```

For details go to the link.

https://medium.com/react-native-development/how-to-use-the-flatlist-component-react-native-basics-92c482816fe6